# TFS Releases keep getting stuck "In Progres"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, release-management

I am using **TFS 2015** on-premise for all our builds and releases. Recently some of our releases have been taking far longer than normal to complete. A release that normally took 20 minutes has been taking several hours.

We release to both on-premise web servers and Azure, and we get the problem with both. It doesn't happen with every release, which makes diagnosing the problem very difficult. We've re-started the **TFS** server but it still keeps happening.

The on-premise releases are just a *Windows Machine File Copy* task and Azure releases are an *Azure Web App Deployment* task. All pretty straight forward. The problem only started recently (over a week or so ago). There have been no updates or changes to the **TFS** server, so can't fathom why this has started happening.

Comment: Whats your Artifact size. ?The initial step of the release is by downloading the artifacts. If your artifact is too big. Then it will take too long to that task. To find the exact issue, I'd recommend looking into the Log tab for the time taken for each task. This would help you to find which task takes more time.

Comment: A release for this particular app is 30MB and has been working perfectly for well ove a year. I'll have a look at the logs and see if I can spot anything though.

Comment: Seems artifact size is not an issue. Try with logs and let us know